# Next step to diagnosing SKScene deallocation issue?

Tags: sprite-kit, dealloc

I have been trying to figure out why one of my SKScenes wont deallocate for quite a while now. I have plugged all leaks according to Instruments, and have used `__weak` references for all `completion` blocks. What is my next step to figuring out why my SKScene won't deallocate? I have `NSLog`'ed the `dealloc` method to confirm it isn't being called, and the allocation heap continues to grow with each new time the game scene is played in instruments.

Comment: strip out code until the scene starts deallocating

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I would do that, but the scene is 4,000 lines. Even if I was going to do that, I'd want a place to start so I wasn't just stripping out random code.

Comment: Begin refactoring. Create a brand new scene and one by one move the code (or nodes) to new scene. 4000 line of code is way too much. Good idea to keep it under at most 1000 lines. As LearnCocoa2D said, strip out code. I'm sure you figure it out.

Comment: Did you pass the scene to another class (e.g., `SKSpriteNode` subclass)? Did you add the scene to an array, dictionary, or set? Perform a global search for `SKScene` and/or the `SKScene` subclass's name that's not being released.

Comment: @0x141E Yes, I do pass the scene to an SKSpriteNode subclass to draw a sprite "forScene:". Is there a way to do this with a weak reference?

Comment: @0x141E nevermind, I already make the weak references and still no deallocating. Is there no way in instruments to see whats going on?

Comment: Look at the `SKSpriteNode` subclass code to see if you are storing a reference to the `SKScene`. You can access the scene within the subclass once you've added the node to the scene, so you don't have to store in an ivar in the subclass. You can access the scene via `node.scene`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a block code, check them also and make sure you nil those blocks holding references to self. When you reference ivars inside blocks, it retains ownership to self.